# Gtk+ Bindings on Beaglebone (arm linux)

Tags: c++, c, linux, gtk, gtk3

I am trying to get Gtk+ working on my Beaglebone Black(armv7l GNU/Linux), very similar to a Raspberry Pi and just about got it except for the Bindings.

I am building the example [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-buildapp-trivial-app.html.en) and got to the point

***exampleappwindow.h***

```
class ExampleAppWindow : public Gtk::ApplicationWindow {
    ...

    Glib::RefPtr<Glib::Binding> m_prop_binding
}
```

I get a error:

```
no member named 'Binding' in namespace 'Glib'
```

I am developing on a Windows 10 pro system using VisualGDB to cross-compile and can't seem to be able to use `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0` anywhere, VisualGDB doesn't seem to know what to do with it so I had to go through and manually setup the libraries and includes off of the pkg-config command, maybe that has something to do with this.

I looked up the GLib::Bindings and found it is declared in `libglibmm` so I thought I needed to install that separate but when I installed `libglibmm2.4-dev` there still isn't `GLib::Binding` or even `glibmm/bindings.h`.

I did a search using `find / -name *binding.h` and there was one file:

```
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h
```

Is this this the base class for gtkmm's binding? I know that the libgtkmm is simply a C++ wrapper, do I need to add a pre-processor definition to include the correct headers?

Am I missing a library or is the Bindings part of the GLib not available for my distro? I am still pretty new at Linux and not sure how to find out whats included in one distro than the other.

I would think that just including `#include <gtkmm.h>` would pull in everything, perhaps I need to explicitly include another library or tell Gtk+ what binding library to use?

Is there a setup step that I didn't do when I installed the gtkmm library? I installed the library using `apt-get install libgtkmm-3.0-dev`

### Edit

I have done a little more work on this and found that the bindings are provided through the dbus-glib bindings. I am not sure if I need a specific version of GLib to enable the bindings or if I need to install another package all together. I have seen references to libdbus-glib2.0-cil so I installed the dev version but still nothing.

There is a command `dbus-binding-tool`, am I supposed to run this command on a file to enable binding? There are references to this command but nothing on how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: GLib::Binding was introduced into the library with version 2.44, check which version you have. If your distribution is based on Debian Jessie it is most likely to have an older version.

Comment: @Errolvandel'Isle I finally got glib2.0 V2.48 installed but still no dice. Can you think of anything else? My details are: Package: libglib2.0-0 Source: glib2.0 Version: 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1

Answer (score 0):

After working on this for a couple of days now I think I came to the conclusion that as of the time of this answer that gtk+ support on the Beaglebone Black is not complete. There is a package `dbus-glib-cli` that does provide binding support but isn't as easy because you have to create a schema file basically then run a compile tool to generate a binding header, very close to how c++ xml binding libraries accomplish.

As I understand it a better approach is to move away from gtk+ and proceed with Qt. It looks like there is allot more support for Qt and everything seems to work right out of the box.

I'm sorry I couldn't publish a fix, but if binding is not necessary or if you want to use the dbus bindings then make sure to install the libgtkmm from the jessie-backports this seems to have some fixes plus removes the dependencies on gtk+ 2.0.

To enable the Backports run:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and un-comment or insert:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

then use

```
sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install libgtkmm-3.0-dev
```

this will install everything that you need for gtk+ including the dbus bindings.